# Should I have been able to melt white chocolate and marshmallows together?

Tags: chocolate, mixing, melting, marshmallow

My daughter and I were making cake pops, and were a little short of white chocolate for the coating. We thought we'd try a white chocolate/marshmallow coating instead. I didn't weigh the marshmallows but they were no more than 25% of the total.

I used a bowl over a pan of simmering water as I usually do for melting chocolate. The white chocolate had mostly melted when I stirred in the marshmallows that were on top. They started to melt then the whole lot seized solid. Further heating didn't help. I was left with something that could be shaped like fondant icing

I've had that happen when heating white chocolate (alone) in the microwave, and always assumed it was local overheating, hence using the bain marie this time.

Now it's cooled, I'm left with something resembling out of date or badly stored white chocolate - grainy rather than creamy.

Is such a coating possible? Should I have gone about it differently? Or is there too much water in marshmallows?

Comment: FWIW, one of the contestants a few years ago on the Great British Baking show used marshmallows (and powdered sugar, but no other ingredients, if I recall correctly) to make fondant.

Comment: Sounds like you made a fudge essentially, though without reaching the boiling point of sugar. The gelatin in the marshmallow would have added the flexibility. Looks like marshmallow has about 20% water, which I wouldn't have thought was too much.

Comment: Judging by your observations of the results alone, it seems like the chocolate seized due to the water in the marshmallows.

Comment: @stan, maybe.  Melting white chocolate is problematic anyway; I've had trouble in the microwave due to local overheating, or possibly stirring.  That's why I do it the old-fashioned way

Comment: @ChrisH, definitely possible. I usually melt chocolate in the microwave in small batches (200g or less at a time), stop to stir every 10s, and stop the microwaving process when it's 80% melted (mostly but with some chunks), and just stir the last 100% using the residual heat in the bowl. This method has worked for me for all kinds of chocolate.

Comment: @stan possible yes, but I have a 1kW microwave which is a bit uneven with small quantities.  10s can be too long for 100-200g of white, but that's the minimum time unless I stop it manually.  I could experiment with lower power, and mine's an inverter model so I wouldn't get the all-or-nothing that you used to with defrost settings, but by that point it's easier to do it on the stove with a bain marie (plus, a small person interrupting makes everything harder but she can stir on the stove)

Comment: @ChrisH, I'm curious, are you using a ceramic bowl, glass or silicon container to microwave your chocolate? I use a ceramic one with a high thermal mass that absorbs a lot of the heat. I suspect the container used may also make a difference. Nonetheless, a bain marie sounds like the right solution in your case.

Comment: @stan A Pyrex (proper borosilicate Pyrex) mixing bowl or ceramic cereal bowl normally.  I tend to use ceramic mugs for melting small quantities but normally need more chocolate than that.  Anyway, the double-boiler approach is proven (and I have a nice ceramic pie dish that sits securely above the water in a small pan so splashing isn't a worry)

Comment: ... white is far less forgiving than milk or dark IME.  This was supermarket own white cooking chocolate, which is normally fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is **definitely possible**, though I should add that the addition of **melted butter would be crucial**.

Do not simply toss "raw" marshmallows into the melted white chocolate, as they will start to cool down the chocolate more than you'd think *(I once tucked my hand into a bag of marshmallows, it was relatively cold in temperature)*.

Here is how I would do it:

1. Melt some butter in a pan *(don't skimp!)*.
2. Toss in your marshmallows and constantly stir them, until all melted and silky.
3. Pour the melted white chocolate into the melted marshmallow & butter, and continue to heat and stir for a few minutes.

Comment: Thats interesting because I was concerned more with overheating the chocolate if I added it to hot marshmallows, rather than with cooling it

Comment: Why is the butter crucial? Why not just pre-melt the marshmallows without butter if temperature is the issue?

Comment: I suspect the butter is crucial because the chocolate would sieze due to the water in the marshmallows, adding the butter (fat) mitigates that problem.

Comment: @stan the reason I'm not completely convinced by this is that butter and marshmallow have very similar water contents: 15%-20%.  I'd be more convinced by a call for pure fat

Comment: @ChrisH it seems to be debated around here if butter and chocolate are a good idea, see this answer and comments: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/3019/76918
It seems like pre-melting the butter makes it less likely to sieze the chocolate.